# Bazel not building correctly. Error with os.bzl

Tags: bazel, drake

I've pulled the most recent drake repo "https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake" and I am trying to

`$run bazel build //...`

but bazel is returning the following error

`ERROR: /home/nathan/drake/tools/workspace/os.bzl:73:13: invalid escape sequence: \(. You can enable unknown escape sequences by passing the flag --incompatible_restrict_string_escapes=false ERROR: /home/nathan/drake/tools/workspace/os.bzl:73:19: invalid escape sequence: \|. You can enable unknown escape sequences by passing the flag --incompatible_restrict_string_escapes=false ERROR: /home/nathan/drake/tools/workspace/os.bzl:73:31: invalid escape sequence: \). You can enable unknown escape sequences by passing the flag --incompatible_restrict_string_escapes=false ERROR: error loading package '': in /home/nathan/drake/tools/workspace/default.bzl: in /home/nathan/drake/tools/workspace/blas/repository.bzl: Extension 'tools/workspace/os.bzl' has errors INFO: Elapsed time: 0.139s INFO: 0 processes. FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)`.

It seems to not like line 73 in os.bzl, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you tell us what revision of Drake you're using, what version of Bazel you're using, and what operating system you're using (macOS, or Ubuntu 18, or Ubuntu 20)?

Comment: I am running Bazel 4.1.0 and Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. For Drake revision, I am at #15079 from the RobotLocomotion repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've just run a build using those same versions of Bazel, Ubuntu, and Drake, with no problems.

There *was* a problem on that line several months ago, that we fixed in https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/12696.  Can you confirm you're using a new-enough version of Drake?  For example, what does `git log -1` report?

Comment: In particular, line 73 should look like this with an `r` at the front:

https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/8b5219748518e02ef095c3eeb7f4e76b256b5f02/tools/workspace/os.bzl#L73

Not like this:

https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/5c3ab7f0cb389db168bebc2ce50f2617aee50e77/tools/workspace/os.bzl#L73

Comment: I repulled and double checked that I was on the most recent branch and it now builds correctly. Thanks for the help!